# ¿Por que getline me captura más de lo que hay en el archivo?

Tags: c++

estoy intentando mostrar un registro hecho con archivos mediante una funcion llamada capturar pero al mostrar, siempre lo hace mal, muestra como si fuera más de un registro, ¿alguien me puede decir que hago mal? Aprendí el tema por mi misma así que quizá no comprendí bien, muchas gracias.

[image: Así es como se ve el archivo]

[image: Este es el output]

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class User{

    public:
        void capture();
        void show();
        void deleteU();
        void searchU();
        void edit();

        string idUser;
        string name;
        string mail;
        string tel;
        string ranking;
        string idProfile;
};

int main(){
    int op;
    User x;
    int z=1;
    cout<<"|||||||||||||||||||||||||||FILE EDITOR|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||"<<endl<<endl;
    while(z!=0){
        cout<<"What do you want to do?"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t 1)Capture"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t 2)Show"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t 3)Delete"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t 4)Search"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t 5)Edit"<<endl;
        cin>>op;

            switch(op)
            {
                case 1:
                    x.capture();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    x.show();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    x.deleteU();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    x.searchU();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    x.edit();
                    break;
                default:
                    cout<<"Your option was invalid, type a valid number."<<endl;
            }
    }
    return 0;
}

void User::capture()
{
    cout<<"Give me the ID USER: ";
    //getline(cin,idUser);
    cin>>idUser;
    cout<<"Give me the NAME: ";
    //getline(cin,name);
    cin>>name;
    cout<<"Give me the MAIL: ";
    //getline(cin,mail);
    cin>>mail;
    cout<<"Give me the TELEPHONE NUMBER: ";
    //getline(cin,tel);
    cin>>tel;
    cout<<"Give me the RANKING: ";
    //getline(cin,ranking);
    cin>>ranking;
    cout<<"Give me the ID PROFILE: ";
    //getline(cin,idProfile);
    cin>>idProfile;

    ofstream write("User.txt",ios::app);
    if (!write.good())
    {
        cout<<"\n\n\tFile not found."<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        write<<idUser<<'|'<<name<<'|'<<mail<<'|'<<tel<<'|'<<ranking<<'|'<<idProfile<<'|'<<'\n';
    }
    write.close();
}
void User::show()
{
    fstream read("User.txt",ios::in|ios::out);
     if (!read.good()){
         cout<<"\n\n\tFile not found."<<endl;
     }
     else{
        while(!read.eof()){
            //string line = getline(read,idUser) + '|' + name + '|' + mail + '|' + tel + '|' + ranking + '|' + idProfile + '|';
            getline(read,idUser);
            getline(read,name);
            getline(read,mail);
            getline(read,tel);
            getline(read,ranking);
            getline(read,idProfile);
            //cout<<line<<endl;
            cout<<idUser<<'|'<<name<<'|'<<mail<<'|'<<tel<<'|'<<ranking<<'|'<<idProfile<<'|'<<'\0'<<endl;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Pista: haz `cout << "Hay datos" << endl; cout<<idUser<< endl; cout << name << endl; cout << "Ya no hay datos" << endl; cout << tel << endl;`

Comment: @SJuan76 Ya lo arreglé, ya vi que estaba haciendo mal, no debo capturar cada una de las strings si no solo 1 vez, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: @SJuan76 hay que intentar que las estadísticas de C++ no caigan... por favor, escribe la respuesta para que la pregunta no quede huérfana...

Comment: @eferion Ah disculpa, ahora la escribo.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu tienes en tu fichero una estructura tal que:

```
Dato1|Dato2|Dato3|Dato4|Dato5|Dato6|
```

Y tu pretendes leer estos datos haciendo uso del separador. Puedes perfectamente usar `getline`... pero no lo estás configurando correctamente:

```
std::getline(std::cin,idUser,'|');
std::getline(std::cin,name,'|');
// ...
```

Por supuesto después de leer el último dato de la fila debes acordarte de eliminar el salto de línea residual para que el bucle de lectura funcione correctamente:

```
std::getline(std::cin,idUser,'|');
std::getline(std::cin,name,'|');
// ...
std::cin.ignore();
```